# registerForContextMenu not working for a parent/child list view

Tags: android

I have a ListActivity which uses a custom ArrayAdapter defining 2 view types, for example

parent 1

- child 11

- child 12

parent 2

- child 21

parent 3

- child 31

- child 32

I have successfully implemented the display functionality I want, but when I register the list view with registerForContextMenu( getListView() ) in the ListActivity the only views that open the Context Menu are the child views, instead I want a long click on the parent views to open the Context Menu.  I've defined the parent view types as enabled and the child as disabled, this only makes both of them ignore the long press event.  Any ideas?  I was going to define the OnLongClick event on the parent views, but I'm not sure how to get ahold of the MenuInflator for the Activity (I have my ArrayAdapter defined in it's own class), should I pass the MenuInflator into my ArrayAdapter??  This seems a little heavy handed, but it may work.

Here's my onCreate call

```
@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) 
{
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.workout_activity );

    _pactAdapter = new WorkoutItemAdapter( this ); 
    setListAdapter( _pactAdapter );
    registerForContextMenu( getListView() );
}
```